# Adding a custom yasnippet directory to `Spacemacs`

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, yasnippet

Sorry for the very newb question, but was just trying to configure a separate directory for `yasnippets` in `spacemacs`. I am not familar with emacs lisp at all. So it says that I can put the directory in

```
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
(auto-completion :variables
auto-completion-return-key-behavior 'complete
auto-completion-tab-key-behavior 'cycle
auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence nil
auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence-delay 0.1
auto-completion-private-snippets-directory nil)
))
```

so I have to set the `auto-completion-private-snippets-directory`, but I was not sure how to configure a custom directory like "~/Dropbox/snippets". I tried the code below with the added directory, but it was not working.

```
dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
...
auto-completion-private-snippets-directory "~/Dropbox/snippets")
))
```

I was not sure if I need to try pushing the new directory to the variable, etc. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to do this. Basically just needed to append directories to the `yas-snippet-dirs` variable. These additional directories are then added to the list of directories from which `yasnippet` gathers snippets.

```
;; Snippet configuration
(setq-default dotspacemacs-configuration-layers '(
  (auto-completion :variables
                   auto-completion-return-key-behavior 'complete
                   auto-completion-tab-key-behavior 'cycle
                   auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence nil
                   auto-completion-complete-with-key-sequence-delay 0.1
           auto-completion-enable-snippets-in-popup t
           auto-completion-enable-sort-by-usage t
           auto-completion-enable-help-tooltip t
                   auto-completion-private-snippets-directory nil)
                   ))

;; add extra snippet directories
(setq yas-snippet-dirs (append yas-snippet-dirs
                               '("/home/<username>/Dropbox/.../snippets")))

(setq yas-snippet-dirs (append yas-snippet-dirs
                               '("/home/<username>/Dropbox/.../more_snippets")))
```

Comment: You should be able to mark your question as resolved ;)